# Чтение и парсинг файла

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, boost

Доброе время суток
Нужно спарсерить файл,струкрура файла:

```
D-Date="02.05.2014 16:00:00"&D-NAS-Ident=10.11.81.66:50130&Acct-Status-Type=3&User-Name="ao250_5038202"&Event-Timestamp=1399032000&Acct-Delay-Time=0&NAS-Identifier="RST-E320-1"&Acct-Session-Id="erx TenGigabitEthernet 0/0/0.35042030:3504-2030:0887085679"&NAS-IP-Address=10.11.81.66&Service-Type=2&Framed-Protocol=1&Framed-Compression=0&ERX-Pppoe-Description="pppoe 00:22:b0:eb:d5:57"&Framed-IP....
```

Вытащить `D-Date`, `User-Name`, `NAS-IP-Address` (Например вывода `D-Date="02.05.2014 16:00:00"`)

Вот что я успел написать, но отказывается искать после 1-го сходства и не дописана структура.Прошу помощи.

```
void __fastcall TForm4::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{
 if(OpenDialog1->Execute()) 
 {
String Text = TFile::ReadAllText(OpenDialog1->FileName);
    Memo1->Lines->Add(Text);

        Application->ProcessMessages();

boost::wregex re(
             L"D-Date=\"(.*?)\"\&"
             L"User-Name=\"(.*?)\"\&"
             L"NAS-IP-Address=(.*?)\&");
boost::wcmatch m;

if(boost::regex_search(Text.c_str(),m,re))
{
    for(size_t i=1; i< m.size(); ++i)
        Memo1->Lines->Add( m[i].str().c_str() );
    Application->ProcessMessages();
}
}
```

Comment: Вы должны описать структуру формально, а не на одном примере. (Если вам дали такое задание, спросите того, кто дал задание.)

В частности, вам придётся ответить на вопросы: какие есть escape-последовательности? Возможны ли пробелы слева от знака `=`? Возможны ли куски без знака `=`? Возможен ли экранированный знак `=`.

Действуйте.

Comment: Простите, не совсем вас понял.Вот сам файл который надо спарсерить https://yadi.sk/d/vIcYRISURhaGi, вот вт если что https://www.virustotal.com/ru/url/8b9e42b0d60a8f67f27216b5e0b853271917cf687f6ad017b323fabab708ec3f/analysis/1401446530/ 
на сколько я смотрел пробелов нету, кусков без = нету, нет.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
к сожалению да

Comment: @woolf24: «сколько я смотрел, нету» не заменяет формальную спецификацию.

---
А как именно важно? Часть кода до `boost::wregex re(` не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме. Вместо `Memo2->Lines->Add` можно было бы просто складывать в список. А `Application->ProcessMessages()` показывает, что вы не умеете многопоточное программирование (извините за прямоту).

Comment: важно показать результат парсинга в Memo не более
Memo2 был у меня лишним, просто для теста парсинга текста, а 1-ый показывал само считывание.

Comment: @woolf24, а можно читаемый образец файла куда-нибудь положить?

Если все записи такого же формата, как в вопросе, то никакого буста с регэкспами Вам не надо.

Достаточно построчного чтения файла с 3-мя `strstr` и `strchr` для каждой строки.

Comment: @avp: Всё-таки писать парсер без точной грамматики — плохая идея. Имеет ли право знак `=` быть заэкранирован и присутствовать в имени ключа? Нужно ли отбрасывать двойные кавычки? И т. д.

Comment: @VladD, понятно, что в общем случае плохая. 

--

Но тут очень похоже, что это просто аргументы GET/POST запросов (причем, наверняка однотипных) собраны в файл, а ТС делает какую-то элементарную сводку.

Comment: @VladD да и я благодарен за это, но проблема в том что надо реализовать именно на с++

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#define  MAX_NUMS   3

bool parse_kv(wchar_t* s, wchar_t* arr[MAX_NUMS]){
    int n = 0;
    wchar_t* p = s;

    const wchar_t* tpls[MAX_NUMS] = {
        { L"D-Date=\""}, { L"User-Name=\"" }, { L"NAS-IP-Address="} 
    };
    const wchar_t* fmts[MAX_NUMS] = { 
        { L"%*[^\"]%n" }, { L"%*[^\"]%n" }, { L"%*[^&]%n" } 
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMS; ++i){
        p = wcsstr(p, tpls[i]);
        if(p == NULL)
            return false;

        p += wcslen(tpls[i]);
        swscanf(p, fmts[i], &n);

        *(p + n) = L'\0';
        arr[i]   = p;
        p       += (n + 1);
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void){
    wchar_t s[] = L"...";

    wchar_t* arr[MAX_NUMS];
    if(parse_kv(s, arr)){
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMS; ++i)
            wprintf(L"%ls\n", arr[i]);
    } else
        _putws(L"Error parse !!!");

    getwchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Эээ... А почему на чистом, аж прозрачном C?

---
У что вы собираетесь делать со строкой

    Fake-D-Date="01.01.2001 01:00:00"&D-Date="02.05.2014 16:00:00"&...

?

Comment: @woolf24: считать текст из файла — простая задача, для неё boost не нужен. И уж это вы должны уметь или найти в гугле за одну минуту. Не ленитесь.

Comment: @woolf24: как вы искали? [google "read+file+line+by+line"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+read+file+line+by+line) -> <http://stackoverflow.com/a/13035743/276994> ->

    std::ifstream file("Read.txt");
    std::string str; 
    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {
        // Process str
    }

Comment: @woolf24: ну вы ж пишете выше: «вроде тут нету ф-ии открытия файла». Мой ответ состоит в том, что её не сложно написать и самому. А остальное вам показали.

---
P. S.: Тут лимит на количество комментариев, удаляйте старые.